# Open a new tab and cache it's last modification date to localStorage

Tags: javascript

I know it's possible to log the current site's last modification date, but is it possible when opening a new tab to cache that documents date to local storage and later fetch it as some variable?

```
    let modified = localStorage.getItem('site')
    let checker = window.open('https://www.exmaple.com', '_blank');
    setTimeout(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('site', this.document.lastModified)
        checker.close()
    }, 1000);
    return false;
```

Comment: Unless you own whatever site the new tab is opening, there's no way for you to get anything from that site. Do you have control over the site on this new tab in question? Because if so, you can always run a script to load the `lastModified` information after a flag has been set.

Comment: i don't sadly, this was purely out of curiosity.

Comment: Then unfortunately as far as my knowledge goes this is impossible. You can't control anything outside your own domain.

Comment: that's not necessarily true, anything on the client-side of a site can be modified, and in this case i was wondering if the date modified in particular can be logged on a **new tab** not current.

Comment: I specifically asked you if the site in the new tab will still be under your own domain. Because if it's something like facebook.com or whatever third party website, there's no way for you to capture it. Which is why if you own the site on the new tab, you can run a script upon loading the page and set a flag, maybe in the URL, indicating that this page was opened via your new tab action -- before running the script to get the document date.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for obvious security reasons.

Quote from the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) (emphasis mine) :

> **Return value**
>
> A WindowProxy object, which is basically a thin
>   wrapper for the Window object representing the newly created window,
>   and has all its features available. If the window couldn't be opened,
>   the returned value is instead null. The returned reference can be used
>   to access properties and methods of the new window **as long as it
>   complies with [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) security requirements**.